# SQL Join with NOT IN() does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have 2 tables that contain both the same key p_id:

```
test1                       test2
+-------------+             +----------------------+
| p_id | name |             | o_id | name  |  p_id |
+-------------+             +----------------------+
|  1   | Paul |             |  1   | London |   1  |
|  2   | Marc |             |  2   | Paris  |   1  |        
+-------------+             +----------------------+
```

Now I want to get all entries from test1 that have no relationship to test2.
In the example above I have abstracted my tables so `RIGHT JOIN` is not possible (in reality I have to join 4 tables).

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM test1 a
LEFT JOIN test2 b
ON a.p_id=b.p_id
WHERE b.p_id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT p_id FROM test2);
```

I expect one row with `p_id=2`. However I get an empty result.
When I change my code into this:

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM test1 a
LEFT JOIN test2 b
ON a.p_id=b.p_id
WHERE a.p_id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT p_id FROM test2);
```

Then it works fine. But why? I thought `LEFT JOIN` is processed first (1 row as result) and after that `WHERE` is processed (JOIN has not found `p_id` in `test2`so `b.p_id` is `null` - `null` is not in subselect - so still 1 row as result).

Could someone explain this behavior, please?

Comment: I see no issues.Your LEFT JOIN gets 2 rows with p_id=1 in the second table But then you exclude those in your subquery

Comment: @RaymondNijland : Sorry, but this is not correct. I have checked with your sugesstion and now I get 2 rows where p_id and test1.name is set and the other columns are null.

Comment: @Mihai : That is not correct. The result of the Left Join are 3 rows (2 with p_id=1 and 1 with p_id=2) and then I exclude the both with p_id=1.

Comment: @RaymondNijland having a where condition on the rhs table of a left join does not automatically turn the left join into an inner one; only conditions that require a non-null value from the rhs table do that.

Comment: @Uueerdo Your comment is generally correct, but in this case the predicate on the outer joined to table in the first SQL statement is indeed "turning the left join into an inner one", because NULL (returned from outer join to unmatched rows) is neither IN nor NOT IN the list of p_id. (Try this illustration: select case when null not in (1, 2, 3) then 'not in' when null in (1, 2, 3) then 'in' else 'neither' end)

Comment: @LordPeter yeah, that is what my answer said; I was just clarifying that merely referencing the rhs table in the WHERE clause of a LEFT JOIN does not convert the join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with how NULL is handled in comparisons.

To test/see, you can run simple queries like:

SELECT 1
FROM DUAL 
WHERE NULL = NULL;

SELECT 1
FROM DUAL 
WHERE NULL NOT IN (1, 2, 3);

Neither return a row because both conditions return NULL which is "not true".

Comment: Do you know if this is specific for MySql? Or does this also apply for e.g. Oracle?

Comment: I haven't played with Oracle in quite a while, and then it was only for a single college course. I believe there may be settings in MySQL to change this behavior, so it may not always be the case even for MySQL. Queries similar to these should be effective in figuring it out for pretty much any SQL RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

As Uueerdo said, it's a NULL comparison issue.  But that aside, you should really use an anti-join:

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM test1 a
LEFT JOIN test2 b
ON a.p_id=b.p_id
WHERE b.p_id IS NULL;
```

It's cleaner and generally more efficient.

Comment: though a not exists may be faster.

Comment: @xQbert Rather old but interesting read here: https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with `NOT IN`, since you are filtering the right table in `Where` clause it is implicitly converted to `INNER JOIN`.

Without the `Where` clause result will be like this

```
+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
| p_id | name |  o_id  |  name  |  p_id  |
+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
|    1 | Paul | 1      | London | 1      |
|    1 | Paul | 2      | Paris  | 1      |
|    2 | Marc | (null) | (null) | (null) |
+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

In this if you are applying the filter

```
WHERE b.p_id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT p_id FROM test2);
```

The sub-query returns `1` which is present in the last column of above result. So you are not getting any result.

In case if you are wondering why the last record having `NULL` is not returned since it is not `1`. It is because `NULL` cannot compared using `=`, `IN`, `NOT IN`,etc.. We need to use `IS` operator for checking `NULL`

Proper way to do this would be using `NOT EXISTS`. Handles `NULL` values as well

```
select * 
from test1 a
Where Not Exists (select 1 from test2 b Where a.p_id = b.p_id)
```

Comment: Not in doens't handle nulls well.  In addition using a where clause on the table on the right side of a left join negates the left join making it act like an inner.  You'd be better off using a anti-join or a not exists.

Comment: @xQbert - No where I mention it as answer. Just explained why it is not returning result.

Comment: @xQbert - Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

In general, WHERE is executed first, then JOIN. Also, when you use LEFT JOIN, it's the LEFT table that has everything included, so your shouldn't expect one row with p_id=2 after the JOIN, as you stated.

Comment: This seems not to be correct: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5038/sql-server-join-where-processing-order The link is about MSDN, but I think it is the same in MySQL.